# How to run a conditional jquery function?

Tags: jquery, click

For the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#erase").click(function(){
    confirm('Are you sure you want to erase it?');
    var data = {
         "post": 123,
     };
    $("#wrapper").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", data)
});
});
</script>
```

The above code returns a confirmatio window with two options Ok and Cancel when the user clicks on the erase link. But irrespective of what they select (Ok or Cancel) the load() function is getting called. How can I prevent the load function if the user is opting out the action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never testing confirm. You need to store the value of a `confirm()` call then, of course, test against it:

```
var proceed = confirm('...');
if (proceed){
  // continue on
}
```

The short-hand to the above would be avoiding an assignment first (which is also perfectly acceptable):

```
if (confirm('...')){
  // proceed
}
```

There's a great write up on MDN about [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) with example usage.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to trigger that function only if user clicks "OK" then here is the code for that

```
$("#erase").click(function(){
   if(confirm('Are you sure you want to erase it?')){

   var data = {
     "post": 123,
    };
   $("#wrapper").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", data)
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

`confirm()` returns true if they clicked Ok, or false if they clicked Cancel. Check the value before continuing.

```
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to erase it?'))
    {
      var data = {
         "post": 123,
       };
      $("#wrapper").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", data)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'confirm' JS-Function is supposed to return a boolean value whether the user selected 'Ok' or 'Cancel'.
just replace

```js
confirm('Are you sure you want to erase it?')
```

with

```
if( !confirm('Are you sure you want to erase it?') )
     return;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Made a quick fiddle to help you out.  http://jsfiddle.net/yPkuZ/

You need to save the response and action on it's results

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#erase").click(function() {
        reply = confirm('Are you sure you want to erase it?');
        if (reply) {
            var data = {
                "post": 123,
        };
        $("#wrapper").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", data)
    } else {
        alert('do nothing');
    }
});
```

});​